# Move rows in csv files - Linux command

Tags: linux, csv, command-line, rows

I have a csv file which has many columns and rows of this type.

foo.csv

```
1 1 x1
1 1 x2
1 1 y1
1 1 y2
. . .
```

What command should I use or what script should I create in order to get it to look like this:

foo.csv

```
1   1   x1   1   1   y1
1   1   x2   1   1   y2
.   .   .     .   .    .
```

In other words, to move the last rows from foo.csv, starting from 1 1 y1, to the columns in the first rows.

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Comment: Is the actual file comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /tmp/1
abc 1
def 2
ghi 3
pqr 4
uvw 5
xyz 6

$ paste <(head -3 /tmp/1) <(tail -3 /tmp/1)
abc 1   pqr 4
def 2   uvw 5
ghi 3   xyz 6
```

Here you take three strings for the first column and threee string for the second.
If you don't known the number of the strings you want to take, you can find it first.

```
$ n=$(cat -n /tmp/1 | grep pqr | cut -f1)
$ paste <(head -$((n-1)) /tmp/1) <(sed 1,$((n-1))d /tmp/1)
abc 1   pqr 4
def 2   uvw 5
ghi 3   xyz 6
```

Comment: Maybe it would be worth counting the lines in the file rather than hard-coding the value. `wc -l < /tmp/1`

Comment: The command works for this two column case. What about if I want this last rows to span on more columns. For example
abc 1
def 2
ghi 3
pqr 4
uvw 5
xyz 6

to 

abc 1 ghi 3 uvw 5
def 2 pqr 4 xyz 6 

?

Comment: @Paul: You can use more arguments to the command than 2, or you can run the command recursively

Answer (score 0):

Adjust awk record selector as neede

```
paste -d " " <(awk '$3~"x"' tests.txt) <(awk '$3~"y"' tests.txt)
```